# Directives - components

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I just work on my directives.

Account-list is my selector and I added it to component.html file by

```
<account-list></account-list>
```

And after I added the components and the syntax I got this message:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'account-list' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'account-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'account-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message. ("
>
> [ERROR ->]
>
> "):

Here is the NGmodule:
[image: 1]

I worked with Udemy course so I wrote what the teacher said.
I couldn't find my problem yet.

Comment: Did you add it to the module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your component in your corresponding NgModule.
[Angular tutorial here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#declare-heroescomponent)

edit: it seems on your screenshot that there is a space in your filename "account list.component" and furthemore you seems to have a webpack: Failed to compile in your bottom panel" can you tell us what is the webpack error ?

Answer (score -1):

[Here is the NGmodule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7F6c.jpg)

I worked with Udemy course so I write what the teacher said.
couldn't find my problem yet